# How did Devise make it mountable inside another engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I am building an engine with the vision that it can be mounted inside another engine, similarly to how devise can be mounted in an engine.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine

I was wondering what steps I would need to take in order to prepare it to be mounted in another engine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great railscast that will get you started:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines